# c++; finding primes in an array

Tags: c++

So, what I am trying to do, is to find the primes in the array.but the
problem is I always get a wrong value,like a array {1, 2, 3, 14, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};I will get count is 37.Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
int countPrimes(int array[], int size)
{
  int count = 0;
       for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
       {
          for(int k = 2;k<array[i];k++)
          {
             if(array[i]%k==0 or array[i]<2)
             {

             }
             else
             {
                count = count +1;
             }
    }
}
     return count;
}
```

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: that's all my code. the main function was given by the website but I can't see it.

Comment: Create a new application (even using an online compiler), include a `main` and an array of primes, then call your function that way.

Comment: `int main() { int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 14, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; std::cout << countPrimes(numbers, 10); }`

Comment: You really need to think about the code logic by yourself. What is the definition of "prime"? What your code is doing?

Comment: Start with an `isPrime` function. When you can conclusively say one number is prime you are in a much better position to say N numbers are prime. See if you can take advantage of memoization to keep from having to look up numbers you've already proved must be prime. Prime number sieving algorithms may help here.

Comment: For each element of the array, your code determines how many numbers less than the element (and greater than 2) are not divisors of the element. The final result (that 37) is the sum of all of the above partial results. Results: for 3 -> 2 (1 number), for 14 -> 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 (10 numbers), for 5 -> 2, 3, 4 (3 numbers), for 6 -> 4, 5 (2 numbers), for 7 -> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (5 numbers), for 8 -> 3, 5, 6, 7 (4 numbers), for 9 -> 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 (6 numbers), for 10 -> 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 (6 numbers). Adding the partial results: 1 + 10 + 3 + 2 + 5 + 4 + 6 + 6 = 37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you must set a flag(**isPrime**) to show number is prime or not and based on the flag count the number of primes. I modified your code:

```
int countPrimes(int array[], int size)
{
  int count = 0;
  bool isPrime;
  for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
  {
     isPrime=true;

     if(array[i]<2)
     { 
        isPrime = false;
     }

     for(int k = 2;k<array[i];k++)
     {
        if(array[i]%k==0 or array[i]<2)
        {
            isPrime=false;           
        }
     }

     if(isPrime)
     {
        count = count +1;
     }
  }

     return count;
}
```

For example in your code for number 14 you increase `count` 10 times because you check if numbers 2 through 13 can divide 14 and actually only 7 and 2 can divide 14 and for 3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13 your condition is true and `count` is increased.

Comment: ur code seems wrong, because let's say the array is{1,2,3}. the final count is 3. clearly, 1 is not  a prime.  But I get your point , thanks.

Comment: when array[i] is 1 then  array[i] < 2  is true and the condition is true and it makes isPrime to false and count is not increased for number 1.
I added a comment on my code

Comment: well, if array[i]==1,for the second for loop, the k is greater than 1. I think that does not satify that condition, so it will not go through that for loop, which is the problem.

Comment: ok, I figured it out, just put if(array[i]<2){ isPrime = false},above the second for loop, the problem will be sloved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code must be like this

```
if(array[i]%k==0)
{
    div_cnt++; // count of divisors, 0 before starting inner loop
}
//there must not be any "else"!
} // end for
if (div_cnt == 2) count++;
```